# git pass different variable to smudge filter according to the project it is invoked from

Tags: git, environment-variables

I want to modify some configuration strings in a git version controlled php script, according to the environment I am using the code in the repository.

I want to set up a smudge/clean filter to modify the configuration string in the code according to the platform, I am checking out (dev/testing). My scripts are in `~/scripts` and I want to add a config file `~/scripts/config` to set values used by the script

I have different projects (in different repos) with the same files in it but they should be modified differently, so the script needs to know from which repository it was invoked.

Is there a way to set a project ID maybe in the `.gitattributes` file which is passed as an environment variable to the filter script?

**EXAMPLE:**

content of `.gitattributes`:

```
PROJECT_ID = "ProjectX"
```

content of smudge script (pseudo code):

```
host = getConfigValueFromFile(projectXhost)
if $PROJECT_ID == "ProjectX" then
    print 'host=$host'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer by myself:

The clean/smudge script is executed with the (new) repos directory as the working directory. So it is possible to put a file e.g. `.projectID` in your repository and read its content in the smudge script.

Answer (score 1):

You can set arbitrary values in the repository configuration.  For example, you can set a variable like this:

```
$ git config mytool.myvariable myvalue
```

And retrieve it like this:

```
$ git config mytool.myvariable
myvalue
```

So your smudge/clean script can simply call `git config mytool.myvariable` and read the output to get the information you've configured.

Comment: the problem with that is, that the repository configuration is not version controlled. So when I clone the project on a different computer, I have lost that information